# Record count in Dashboards

Tags: reporting, dashboard, filters

I have a Dashboard with two components. Each component has its own source report. These two components already has record count field based on certain filter criteria(given in the source report).

My requirement is to add another record count field to these Dashboard components based on another filter logic.

Is this possible? Or do I need to modify the report filter itself to new filter condition and get the single record count based on updated logic?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If your question is, can you add a 3rd column to your dashboard the answer is yes. I originally was going to try and explain this - but I will simply point you to SFDC documentation https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000003933&language=en_US

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest if on update of filter you get appropriate count then go ahead with that approach .As it is straight out of box .

Comment: Thanks Mohith! U mean to say that it is not possible to add more than one record count to a component in Dashboard?

Comment: Yes thats right we may not be able to add that .